# iOS 11 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

My app is working fine on iOS 10 and below. But app crashed on 11 and 12.

Here is the crash log from my device.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
 Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
 Termination Description: DYLD, can't resolve symbol __ZN8TVIMetal4Math6lookAtERKDv3_fS3_S3_ in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DF302F8-4470-4609-B90B-B6FDF2583597/MyApp.app/MyApp because dependent dylib #32 could not be loaded
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   dyld                            0x0000000105de8264 __abort_with_payload + 8
    1   dyld                            0x0000000105de78a4 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
    2   dyld                            0x0000000105de78d4 fcntl + 0
    3   dyld                            0x0000000105da88f4 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18676 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 0
    4   dyld                            0x0000000105da8a10 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18960 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 284
    5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001d9446bb0 dyld_stub_binder + 60
    6   MyApp                           0x00000001050cf6e4 -[TVIMetalRenderer prepareTransforms] + 6682340 (TVIMetalRenderer.mm:211)
    7   MyApp                           0x00000001050cf1c8 -[TVIMetalRenderer configure:] + 6681032 (TVIMetalRenderer.mm:142)
    8   MyApp                           0x00000001050fed8c -[TVIMetalVideoView initWithFrame:delegate:] + 6876556 (TVIMetalVideoView.m:80)
    9   MyApp                           0x00000001050ca10c -[TVIVideoView initWithFrame:delegate:renderingType:] + 6660364 (TVIVideoView.mm:109)
    10  MyApp                           0x00000001050c9ed4 -[TVIVideoView initWithFrame:delegate:] + 6659796 (TVIVideoView.mm:81)
    11  MyApp                           0x00000001050c9e2c -[TVIVideoView initWithFrame:] + 6659628 (TVIVideoView.mm:73)
    12  MyApp                           0x00000001050c9868 -[TVIVideoView awakeAfterUsingCoder:] + 6658152 (TVIVideoView.mm:26)
    13  UIFoundation                    0x00000001e4017efc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 860
    14  UIFoundation                    0x00000001e3fb6b3c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
    15  UIKitCore                       0x00000002064a53b4 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 188
    16  UIFoundation                    0x00000001e4017e88 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744
    17  UIFoundation                    0x00000001e40180cc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1324
    18  UIFoundation                    0x00000001e3fb6b3c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
    19  UIKitCore                       0x00000002064a2cb4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1124
    20  UIKitCore                       0x00000002062343d0 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 372
    21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206234d7c -[UIViewController loadView] + 176
    22  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206235044 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    23  UIKitCore                       0x00000002062357b0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
    24  UIKitCore                       0x00000002061684c8 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 88
    25  UIKitCore                       0x000000020615c79c -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 136
    26  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206246c98 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2640
    27  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206249cb8 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 68
    28  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206c8dfe0 +[UIView+ 14127072 (Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104
    29  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206249c18 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 212
    30  UIKitCore                       0x000000020624a210 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 512
    31  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206249b04 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 180
    32  UIKitCore                       0x0000000206249e40 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 160
    33  MyApp                           0x00000001050c46a0 startVideo + 6637216 (video.m:44)
    34  MyApp                           0x0000000104e6a4dc main + 3084248
    35  MyApp                           0x00000001050268d8 main + 4903892
    36  MyApp                           0x0000000105026efc main + 4905464
    37  MyApp                           0x0000000105026b04 main + 4904448
    38  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    39  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    40  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    41  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    42  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    43  MyApp                           0x0000000105024888 main + 4895620
    44  MyApp                           0x0000000104a7a20c 0x104a70000 + 41484
    45  MyApp                           0x0000000104a79d88 0x104a70000 + 40328
    46  MyApp                           0x0000000104a78e2c 0x104a70000 + 36396
    47  MyApp                           0x0000000104ca73c8 main + 1236676
    48  MyApp                           0x00000001050268d8 main + 4903892
    49  MyApp                           0x0000000105026efc main + 4905464
    50  MyApp                           0x0000000105026b04 main + 4904448
    51  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    52  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe8b00 main + 4650492
    53  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    54  MyApp                           0x0000000105001c30 main + 4753196
    55  MyApp                           0x0000000104fea31c main + 4656664
    56  MyApp                           0x0000000104fe6554 main + 4640848
    57  MyApp                           0x0000000105024888 main + 4895620
    58  MyApp                           0x0000000104a7a20c 0x104a70000 + 41484
    59  MyApp                           0x0000000104a7aaf4 0x104a70000 + 43764
    60  MyApp                           0x0000000104d18a88 main + 1701252
    61  MyApp                           0x0000000104da31c8 main + 2268356
    62  MyApp                           0x0000000104b43b1c 0x104a70000 + 867100
    63  MyApp                           0x0000000104b50858 0x104a70000 + 919640
    64  MyApp                           0x0000000104b50dd4 0x104a70000 + 921044
    65  MyApp                           0x0000000104a8ed5c 0x104a70000 + 126300
    66  QuartzCore                      0x00000001ddeb1574 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items+ 66932 (unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 828
    67  IOKit                           0x00000001d9c5b58c IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 488
    68  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d99633e4 __CFMachPortPerform + 188
    69  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d998ac30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    70  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d998a37c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
    71  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d9985134 __CFRunLoopRun + 2140
    72  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d99845b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    73  GraphicsServices                0x00000001dbbf8584 GSEventRunModal + 100
    74  UIKitCore                       0x00000002067f8bc8 UIApplicationMain + 212
    75  MyApp                           0x0000000104b79558 main + 84
    76  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001d9444b94 start + 4
```

The error here is  dependent dylib #32 could not be loaded. 
But i would like to know what is actually dylib #32?.
I have added the following dylib files in Linked binaries and framework.

libicucore.dylib,
libresolv.dylib,
libxml2.dylib,
libc++.dylib,
libz.dylib

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: try to run your transformations in main queue.

Comment: Hai 
thanks for the quick response. Actually i am a beginner. Can you please explain little bit?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` put your ui update method where you are getting crash in this block.

Comment: Can you please explain what is mean by dylib #32  and why the app crash on iso 11 or above?

Comment: I have tried like this 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [app.keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:myViewController animated:false completion:nil];
    });
But still app crashed.